# python selenium accept cookie iframe

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I'm new in python and selenium and I need help. I can not accept cookie in to the iframe

Anybody can help me please?

Thanks

```
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from seleniumwire import webdriver

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe'

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=options)


driver.get('https://autoscout24.de/')
time.sleep(5)
# go to iframe accept cookies
driver.switch_to.frame("gdpr-consent-notice")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[class='mat-focus-indicator solo-button mat-button mat-button-base mat-raised-button cdk-focused cdk-mouse-focused'] div[class='action-wrapper']").cick()



# back to previous frame
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
time.sleep(5)


driver, quit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see **ID** is unique then you do not need `CSS Selector` at all.

You should induce [Explicit waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait) to switch to `iframe`.

They allow your code to halt program execution, or freeze the thread, until the condition you pass it resolves. The condition is called with a certain frequency until the timeout of the wait is elapsed. This means that for as long as the condition returns a falsy value, it will keep trying and waiting.

**Code :**

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'C:\\geckodriver.exe', firefox_options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://autoscout24.de/')
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.ID, "gdpr-consent-notice")))
button = driver.find_element_by_id('save')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)


# back to previous frame
driver.switch_to.parent_frame()
time.sleep(5)
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```